# C++ Create popup window

Tags: c++, api, popup, window

I want to make a popup window appear when I hit a button that is located on the main window of my program. I have looked everywhere for popup window examples, and most answers just showed me how to make a window, buttt I already have a main window in my application.

Basically the difficulty I am having is knowing where to put the new window class and code for my popup window(since I want the pop window to have different properties than my main one). Should it also be in the WinMain function or should it be in one of the cases in the CALLBACK WndProcedure section?

some of the code I have for my window is:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;

wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    g_szClassName,
    "The title of my window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if(hwnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

I just am not sure where to put it... Should it be placed in the code that is activated when the button is pressed, or should it stay in the WinMain function, together with the information of the other window?

I hope you can understand my predicament, I am somewhat new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new window should be created in the case statement in your wndProc that handles the button click.

Comment: Ok so I would call the CreateWindowEx function in the case statement, perfect. Should the making of the window class and the registering of the window class also happen in that case statement, or should it happen in the WinMain function? (or somewhere else?)

Comment: Hi scott, I  tried making a popup window, but I am getting where I am making a new window popup that is a copy of my main program window. Could u possibly see what is wrong with the code there? Here is the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331543/c-issue-with-creating-popup-window-getting-other-window-instead

Answer (score 2):

Register window at main() together with main window. And in case statement of WndProc call CreateWindowEx().

But I don't know how make animation of popup. I can imagine that code should put somewhere in the WM_CREATE, but this I don't know.

if you mean just another window for example window for settings you should use DialogBoxes.

P.S. If you are russian, then I strongly recommend the book "Win32 API. Effective Application Development" by Yuri Shchupak on russian

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I am not looking to make a menu. I am simply trying to make a pop up window, that later on will display whatever information i need it to. The issue I am having is... I am not sure where I should be writing the bits of code. Like I understand I need to put CreateWindowEx() in the case statement in my windProc, however where should code for the window class for the popup window be written, as well as when should I register it? should all this happen in the windProc case statement, or should it be done wayy in the beginning of the progam?

Comment: @rsthegreat12 oh ****!! Is popup window xD it's complicated question:) I think that you need register window at main() together with main window.  And in case statement of WndProc call CreateWindowEx(), but I don't know how make animation of popup. I can imagine that code should put somewhere in the WM_CREATE, but this I don't know. Usually for additional windows use DialogBoxes.

Comment: hehe ok thanks for the feedback. I mean I don't believe it should be that complicated since I am always using programs with popup windows, but I haven't really found the answer online for a while now, so it is a bit confusing :).